# Deploy Multiple services in same host/Machine with juju?

Tags: juju

Currently juju deploy service per node. Is that possible to deploy many services in the same node [even specify existant node]?

There is juju-jitsu as alternative to do that !!! Does anyone had experience or feedback with it ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its 2 of us in a team. We just playing with charms to see the possibilities. We deployed
8 charms on one machine and it worked.

```
jitsu deploy-to "machine name" "service name"
```

Also you can use your local repo with edited config.yaml to deploy services or create a config file for all services and use it when deploying.

But still I have some problems understanding the networking part in it. We have only one week experience with charms, cant say personally about the production implementation. But it looks OKey. Maybe "charms" will live to my expectations.